# Find upcoming DATE from "Tuesday"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good Morning,

I have the following right now:

| Column A | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| 21 Juli | row |
| Tomorrow | row |
| Tuesday | row |
| Friday | row |
| 23 Juli | row |

I want to change Tomorrow to the date tomorrow and change Friday to the next date of Friday, same for Tuesday etc.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOw7fJO8c-ZgKPRTxWYjRW7ZpA9NDeC7Iw41wLGMZP8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 TEXT(SEQUENCE(8, 1, TODAY()+8, -1), {"dddd", "dd mmmm"}), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

then you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 TEXT(SEQUENCE(8, 1, TODAY()+8, -1), {"dddd", "dd mmmm"}), 2, 0), A3:A))
```

[image]

and for tomorrow:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 TEXT(SEQUENCE(8, 1, TODAY()+8, -1), {"dddd", "dd mmmm"}), 2, 0), A3:A), 
 "Tomorrow", TEXT(TODAY()+1, "dd mmmm")))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you didn't see this in image 2, next fridy is 7/22/2022

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you.

The only thing that is missing now which I thought i could solve myself but unf not, We also have 1 date which is "1 - 2 weeks", which would convert to 8 days counted on top of the current date. @Osm

Comment: He only missed this. I was stuck at that point as well, with a different approach. and a longer formula.

Comment: @Osm can be easily "fixed" by changing 8 to 7 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHghO.png

Comment: I tried this but I still dont get it to work. See Image https://imgur.com/a/jsB4e9L @osm

Comment: @Osm if you tried it now/recently its actually fine coz we already moved to the next week window

Comment: @player0 I checked the next day name, still persisting I cant figure out a way to be done in one formula.